# Make axios call from another axios promise and save returned data

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I am making an axios call from promise of another `axios` call, the code looks like below, the call is basically from the first method to the second method.

**UPDATED CODE BASED ON SUGGESTION**
It simply says: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function then I tried

```
var data = async () => {
        await this.checkParentLoggerLevel();
      };
```

still did not work

```
async updateLevel(logger, level, index) {
      alert(index);
      axios
        .post(
          'url'
        )
        .then(() => {
          var data = await this.checkParentLoggerLevel();

          alert('waiting');
          alert(
            'This will be executed before the second methods returns HEllo'
          );
          alert(data);
        });
    },
```

Second method:

```
async checkParentLoggerLevel() {
      alert('inside checkParentLoggerLevel ');
      return await axios
        .get('url')
        .then(() => {
          alert('returning hello');
          return 'hello';
        });
    },
```

My aim to to save the returned `hello` to data variable in first method.This is not working. The other problem is after the `this.checkParentLoggerLevel()` methods call code execution continues and does not wait for the retuned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because inside `checkParentLoggerLevel` you are not waiting for the `axios` promise to complete. You can do it like:

```
async checkParentLoggerLevel() {
  alert('inside checkParentLoggerLevel ');
  return await axios
    .get('url')
    .then((res) => {
      return 'hello';
    });
}
```

Also, you need to await inside `updateLevel` like:

```
async updateLevel() {
  axios
    .post(url)
    .then(async (res) => {
      var data = await this.checkParentLoggerLevel();
      alert("This will be executed before the second methods returns HEllo");
      alert(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: `return await`  does only make sense when it is inside of a `try-catch` block. If it isn't you can just remove the  `await`. `return await` work, it just does not make to much sense.

Comment: @Zuckerberg When using  var data = await this.checkParentLoggerLevel(); It says Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: ok, then try making the function async like `async updateLevel() {`

Comment: The `await this.checkParentLoggerLevel()` would not work now because  the arrow function `(res) => { … }` in which it is, is not marked `async`. Before the edit it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the promises, so:

```js
updateLevel() {
  axios
    .post(url)
    .then(res => {
      return this.checkParentLoggerLevel.then(data => ([res, data]);
    })
    .then(([res, data]) => {
       // here
    });
}
```

Or simply with async await:

```js
async updateLevel() {
  const res = await axios.post(url);
  const data = await this.checkParentLoggerLevel();
  // Do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: When const data = await this.checkParentLoggerLevel();; It says Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: you must ensure as I wrote in the answer that `updateLevel` is marked as `async`